# Using script file like a function

Tags: clojure, lua

In lua, I can do something like this:

```
a.lua:
return 1+2

b.lua:
print(dofile('a.lua'))
```

My question is: Does this kind of thing (using files like functions) has a standarized name in computer science? What languages besides lua support it? Particularly, can you do something like this in Clojure? (or Lisp)

Comment: In most languages, a source file corresponds - not to a single function - but to a package/module/namespace, which can contain many things, some of which may be functions. Are you sure you want your file to behave as a single parameterless function *evaluation*?

Comment: @Thumbnail That's how it works in Lua; files are simply vararg (not parameterless) functions. This is actually very nice, as now you can do anything with a 'file' that you could do with a normal function (call it multiple times, set a debug hook or function environment, etc). If you want packages/modules/namespaces, you can return a table.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo In the words of the [Lua reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-dofile), `dofile` *opens the named file and executes its contents as a Lua chunk*. The file in the example consists of a single return *statement*, one kind of *chunk*: no mention of function definitions or calls anywhere, though I'm guessing that either could crop up in the chunk file. This seems a lot like Lisp, of whatever dialect.

Comment: @Thumbnail `dofile` is a shortcut for opening and reading a file, compiling the Lua code, and executing it; `loadstring` has the behavior I stated.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Lua's `loadstring` is part of the auxiliary library (a C interface), operates on a C string (not a file), and isn't in the example. I think what you are looking for is `lua_load`, part of the C API, which works on a (file) reader, doing much the same as Clojure's `read` does.

Comment: @Thumbnail `lua_load` is the lowest-level way of loading Lua code; everything else is built on top of it. The reader you pass doesn't have to read from a file; it can be anything. And it pushes the loaded code as a function onto the stack, which is how I described it working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54135/discussion-between-thumbnail-and-colonel-thirty-two).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clojure equivalent would be

```
a.clj:
(+ 1 2)

b.clj:
(load-file "a.clj")
```

but please note that clojure namespaces would be the right approach.
In b.clj you can :use or :require/:refer select functions from any namespace.

To your second question you may want to lookup [linkers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29).

Answer (score 2):

```
(eval (read-string "(+ 1 2)"))
; 3
```

Use [`read`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/read) instead of [`read-string`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/read-string) to read from a file. But beware! This executes whatever code is in the file.

---

Note

`read` and `read-string` evaluate the first form they find. `load-file` (as in [@KobbyPemson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23782322/1562315)) evaluates the lot, returning the result of the last, as though they were surrounded by an invisible `do`.

Given

```
(defn read-file [filename]
  (with-open [r (java.io.PushbackReader. (clojure.java.io/reader filename))]
             (eval (read r))))

(spit "testfile.txt" "(+ 1 2) 3 4")
```

then

```
(eval (read-string "(+ 1 2) 3 4"))
; 3

(read-file "testfile.txt")
; 3

(load-file "testfile.txt")
; 4
```

(adapted from [ClojureDocs on `read`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/read))